# Error after switching from ODBC DSN connection to OLEDB

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, odbc, oledb

I've been having timeout and login connection issues from my ASP application to my SQL Server database. My hosting provider suggested changing my connection string from ODBC DSN to OLEDB. Once I did that I get this error when executing my first stored procedure.

> Procedure or function 'storedproc' expects parameter '@param1', which
>   was not supplied.

Here is my connection string

```
Dim objconn
Set objconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objconn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=db;user id=user;password=pw"
```

Here is my stored proc call

```
Dim objrs, cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = objconn
cmd.CommandText = "storedproc"
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameters("param1",adDouble,adParamInput,,session("param1")))
Set objrs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objrs.CursorLocatoin = adUseClient
objrs.Open cmd
```

Any ideas why my proc call doesn't work with a different connection string?

Comment: You say CreateParameters, but that should be CreateParameter and you should not enclose the create statement in brackets, AFAIK. It works for me with both ODBC & OLEDB once these changes are made.

Comment: did you try actually naming the parameter `"@param1"` instead of `"param1"`?

Comment: @Remou:  you meant the call to `Append` need not have parantheses right?

Comment: Yes. I do. Not just need not, but should not, as far as I know. I tested with VBScript, and I am fairly sure the same rules apply.

Comment: @Remou: yes they do and I agree they _should_ not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typos, `.CreateParameters => .CreateParameter` and `.CursorLocatoin => .CursorLocation`
I've ignored them because looks like typos only applies to the question.

[CommandType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If the CommandType property value is set to the default value,
>   adCmdUnknown, you may experience diminished performance because ADO
>   must make calls to the provider to determine if the CommandText
>   property is an SQL statement, a stored procedure, or a table name. If
>   you know what type of command you are using, setting the CommandType
>   property instructs ADO to go directly to the relevant code. If the
>   CommandType property does not match the type of command in the
>   CommandText property, an error occurs when you call the Execute
>   method.

As I understand, action is vary depending to the provider when the `CommandType` is not specified.
I tracked the queries using the SQL Server Profiler. What I saw is with OLEDB Provider, the command objects without CommandType property executes a query without parameter on the background something like that  : `Exec storedproc`, this means it works properly if the procedure is parameterless. However it should have been `Exec storedproc parametervalue`. On the other hand, same code works like a charm on MySQL as you said. 

So, need to specify `cmd.CommandType` as `adCmdStoredProc` that equals to **4**, then your code will work.
 
BTW, It's **-1** (`adCmdUnknown`) by default.